# Service to display simple JSON data send from ERP system

Tags: json, erp

We have an ERP system and my task is to find a way how to allow my customers to see their current stock in our system. My initial idea was to automate task on our server that would send http request with JSON that I can easily put together.

Is there any service around that would accept the JSON and create separate endpoint that my customer could access? I am no programmer but I am able to put some simple webapp that would display the data.

For security reasons I don't want to share my API Endpoint with my customers so they can access it.

Am I overthinking it too much? Is there anyone who could recommend me how I could go about that?